# Abstract property without setter

Tags: c#, properties, abstract

I am writing some code, and I found that when I create a new abstract property without setter, I can't set its value in the constructor. Why is this possible when we are using a normal property? What's the difference?

```
protected Motorcycle(int horsePower, double cubicCentimeters)
{
    this.HorsePower = horsePower; //cannot be assigned to -- it is read only
    this.CubicCentimeters = cubicCentimeters;
}

public abstract int HorsePower { get; }

public double CubicCentimeters { get; }
```

It's obvious that if we want to set it in the constructor, we should use protected or public setter.

Comment: because it's abstract

Comment: @ZoharPeled Not entirely, if you add a `set` it will work.

Comment: @ZoharPeled, and what of this?

Comment: @DavidG see Dmitry's answer for an explanation.

Comment: @ZoharPeled I know, I'm just saying your comment isn't entirely correct.

Comment: @DavidG there's a difference between readonly and read/write properties. a readonly property does not require a backing field as Dmitry's answer shows - but a read/write property does require one - and since this is an abstract property, the compiler will not allow setting a readonly property value in the constructor of the abstract class. If it wasn't an abstract property, the compiler would be perfectly happy with a constructor assignment - in short - because it's abstract. A comment is not an answer - if I would write "because it's abstract" as an answer, I would deserve downvotes.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Yes, I know all this, but the comment on it's own is slightly misleading, which is why I replied.

Comment: @DavidG well I wrote a comment because I didn't want to write a full answer because I'm too tired to write a good answer. (of course by now, seems like I've wasted at least the same amount of energy on this anyway) - so I just wrote a single sentence shining a light on what I think is the right answer. It's a comment, it doesn't have to be a complete answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes you have *compile time error* since there's no guarantee, that `HorsePower` has a *backing field* to assign to. Imagine,

```
 public class CounterExample : Motorcycle {
   // What "set" should do in this case? 
   public override int HorsePower { 
     get {
       return 1234;
     }
   }

   public CounterExample() 
     : base(10, 20) {}
 }
```

What should `this.HorsePower = horsePower;` do in this case?

Comment: Thank you! I am trying to understand it. If we have setter in the overridden property,  it will be ok, right? (ignoring that we are having compile-time error)

Comment: @Kite [you can't add a setter in the overriden property.](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAICGAjAzgFwCdMBjfdWdAYXQG9l1GnGGm0s8jTyBLAO3IAFQgHsADnQDmAU3wBuAL7IlSZO0oARdCGrJ6SZuxEA3aYUI9g09PyGiJtGfNyzFyoA)

Comment: @Kite: yes, if we have `set` in both `abstract` (and in `overriden`) property we have guarantee that rain or shine we can assign the value. If we have `set` in overiden property only (which we are not allowed) then some classes (like `CounterExample`) can well *not have* it and we still have a problem in `abstract` class

Answer (score 0):

The abstract keyword in c# specifies classes or members that the implementation must be provided by the derived class.